# Prepend lines with file prefix using sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

How do I change a sample input file so as to get something like the output file below?

Input file:

```
/tmp/logs
10/13/15 00:19:13 templogs1
10/13/15 00:19:13 dummylogs
10/13/15 01:19:12  test
10/13/15 01:19:12 error
/tmp/error
10/13/15 00:16:10 x
10/13/15 00:16:10 y
10/13/15 01:16:10 z
10/13/15 01:16:10 a
/tmp/access
10/13/15 00:56:14 b
10/13/15 00:56:14 c
```

Output file:

```
/tmp/logs 10/13/15 00:19:13 templogs1
/tmp/logs 10/13/15 00:19:13 dummylogs
/tmp/logs 10/13/15 01:19:12  test
/tmp/logs 10/13/15 01:19:12 error
/tmp/error 10/13/15 00:16:10 x
/tmp/error 10/13/15 00:16:10 y
/tmp/error 10/13/15 01:16:10 z
/tmp/error 10/13/15 01:16:10 a
/tmp/access 10/13/15 00:56:14 b
/tmp/access 10/13/15 00:56:14 c
```

Comment: `awk '{print FILENAME, $0}'`

Comment: Although you specifically ask using sed/awk it can also be achieved using grep (adds a colon though), `grep . /tmp/logs /tmp/error /tmp/access`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `sed`

```
sed '
    /^\//{                    # execite block if line start with «/»
        h                     # put line into hold-space
        d                     # clean, return to beginning
        }                     # end block
    G                         # append hold-space to line
    s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/   # exchange first and last part of line
    ' input.file > output.file
```

and other variant

```
sed '
    /^\//{                    # execute from line started with «/»
        :1                    # mark return point
        N                     # get next line
        /\n\//D               # if such next line started «/» remove previous
                              #+and starts from the beginning with last line
        s/\n/ /p              # change newline with space and prints both lines
        s/ .*//               # removes last line
        $!b1                  # return to marked point with fist line if not end
        d                     # clean all (finish)
        }
    ' input.file > output.file
```

Comment: You super cool, all 3 answers works as expected. It would be very great if you could explain any of the above command.

Comment: @ChitthaShetty Have comments added

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Something goes over my head, do you have any good reference for sed and awk to start with.

Comment: @ChitthaShetty From online resources http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html and main book is «Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide»

Answer (score 0):

try

```
awk 'substr($1,1,1) == "/"  { prefix=$0 ; next ; }
   { printf "%s %s\n",prefix,$0;}'
```

this will capture prefix when they begin with '`/`' ...

Comment: Use `substr` is too much `awk '/^\//{prefix=$0;next}{print prefix, $0}'`